# Add calculated column with checkboxes to datagrid

Tags: delphi, datagrid

In my application I have a TcxGrid (devexpress datagrid) that displays the data returned from a stored procedure.
Now I would like to add a column showing checkboxes from which the values cannot come from the database but are calculated internally.
When the checkboxes are clicked, some internal logic needs to be triggered.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@boris, I recommend you use the [Support Center site of DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) for this type of question, there are thousands of articles to DevExpress products.

Anyway I leave here a link to something that might help ;)

- [How to set up an unbound item in a data-aware View](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1095.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but then I'm still waiting for a reply from my company regarding the registration credentials... Also, I really like SO

Comment: Although I'm noticing I mainly liked it because the C# community here was so vibrant and huge..

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the view at runtime or at designtime?

I sort of cheated when I did this at runtime, and returned a static value as one column from my query:

```
select false as processed,col1,col2 from table where true
```

I could then safely attach the dataset, and I had my new column to play with.

You would then perhaps use the properties.onChange or properties.onEditValueChanged for your logic code.

Comment: I used the query to actually populate a kbmMemTable for edits, then I just created a custom resolver and processed the marked rows - the link RRUZ gave is probably your best bet anyway